# Finding duplicate numbers in an array, containing multiple digits

Tags: arrays

How do you find duplicate numbers in an array if it contains multiple duplicates?

I first tried using LinkedHashMap. However, I need two iterations, but if I don't have two, how do I solve the problem? Should I try using a different programming method?

Comment: Which language? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Is it in [Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html)?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.